# Custom loss function for binary classificatio in Keras gets error: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: classification, keras, loss-function, binary-classification

I have a binary classification problem. However, I don't really care about `fp` and `fn` values. What I want to achieve is that the `fp + tp` gets close to `tp+fn`.

In other words, the sum all predicted labels as `positive` should be close to the sum of all real `positive` labels. To make my network go to this direction, I use a custom loss function, which aims to calculate the difference between `fp + tp` and `tp+fn`.

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
def loss_func(y_true,pred):

    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    mseos = K.abs(K.sum(pred) - K.sum(y_true))
    return mseos

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(X_df.shape[1], X_df.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss=loss_func, optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The problem with this code is: the `pred` is not a binary tensor with `0` and `1` values, instead, it has float numbers between `0` and `1`.

If I try to round the `pred` values (e.g. `K.round`) or convert it to binary to count the number of `1`s, I get the following error:

`ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:`

Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: And what happens if you just don't round `pred`?

Comment: If I don't round the `pred`, I don't get any error. But the logic is different than what I want. Basically `pred` values are between 0 and 1 (likelihood of being `positive`), I want to calculate the sum of positive labels. All the values more than 0.5 should be considered as 1.

Comment: Doesn't the maximum of the rounded version match that of the round-less version? Have you tried empirically to see if the results are Ok?